# Why did the author write "Why?"? Any deep reason? ("Calculus Fourth Edition" by Michael Spivak)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, soft-question, riemann-integration

> **THEOREM 6** If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then for any number $c$, the function $cf$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $$\int_a^b cf=c\cdot\int_a^b f.$$
>
> **PROOF** The proof (which is much easier than that of Theorem 5) is left to you. It is a good idea to treat separately the cases $c\geq 0$ and $c\leq 0$. **Why?**

I wonder why the author Michael Spivak wrote "Why?".
Is there any deep reason?

**My Proof :**
I think it is very natural to treat separately the cases $c=0$ and $c>0$ and $c<0$ because

- it is obvious that $\int_a^b cf=0=c\cdot\int_a^b f$ if $c=0$ and
- $L(cf,P)=cL(f,P)$ and $U(cf,P)=cU(f,P)$ holds if $c>0$ and
- $L(cf,P)=cU(f,P)$ and $U(cf,P)=cL(f,P)$ holds if $c<0$.

Comment: sounds fine to me

Comment: Ditto. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Do you really need to handle the case $c=0$ separately though? If we can trim the proof slightly with zero extra effort we might as well do so.

Comment: Andrew, copper.hat and littleO, thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: Couldn't you just use the definition for riemann sums?

Comment: @KamalSaleh proving the equivalence of Riemann’s definition with Darboux’s definition (even though it’s an invaluable exercise) is more work than proving this little theorem.

Comment: I think the Question is not whether we want to club $0$ with the other cases or make it a new case. It is about why Spivak is including the "why" when suggesting to make it separate cases. In other words , "why not Prove it for all $c$ in one shot?" : +1 for valid Query. It is okay to make it 2 cases or even 3 cases. Why Spivak is suggesting to not make it 1 Case ? OP has the Proof , which looks right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a Soft Question & the Author is unfortunately not around to give the Definitive Answer.

The way I am looking at it , it is because of the way the integral was given on Page 258 & Page 259 :

[image: Page 258]

[image: Page 259]

It is using $\le$ everywhere.
When we want to Prove theorem 6 (or whichever exercise) , we have to be careful about that.
Of course , we can multiply both sides by Positive (or even $0$) $c$ while keeping that relation unchanged.
When multiplying both sides by Negative (or even $0$) $c$ , we have to change the relation to $\ge$ or we have to switch the sides.

Tracking that is easier when we have separate cases.
Thus Spivak is suggesting that.
It is a **Suggestion** & we can work without that , though it **might** be slightly harder to keep track at **early learning stages** where that complication is unnecessary & avoidable.

Proving the earlier theorems [ including theorem 5 & theorem 2 ] necessitates using $\le$ & $\ge$ : Spivak is very careful when using those.

ADDENDUM :
Proof can alternately consider Positive $c$ & $c=0$ & then $c=-1$ : That too will cover all Cases , though it is more work.